# Formating 12 hour timings to 24 hrs in CakePhp

Tags: jquery, cakephp, time

I am facing a problem with converting 12 hr timing to 24 hrs timing. I know that cakephp automatically convert the 12 hrs into 24 hrs format and save it in the database.
In my table time showing 18:30:00, but when i display in the view cake automatically convert it into 6:30 PM.
but my problem is i am trying to save 6:30 PM from a select box to  a table by ajax call.
i am getting time from the select box using jquery. after that when i save it into database it showing 06:30:00. I want to convert it into 24 hr format..
if anybody know please help me...i am struggling with this problem.

this is the jquery code i wrote to select value from select box

```
var evening_time =$('#eveningTime :selected').text
```

is there any way to convert this format from the controller function???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the `timeFormat` option. [See](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#datetime-options).